# How to make a map on JSON object with children

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My menu consists of sub menu, that's why my JSON is composed like this:

"Accueil" -> "Espace documentaire"

"Déploiement" -> "Indicateurs de déploiement", "Fichiers NetGeo", "Fichiers STBAN" ...

So I want to make a menu with a Treeview that initially displays the map "Accueil"
then the (children) "Espace documentaire"

Here is the JSON object:

https://pastebin.com/km399QFQ

Here is the function:

```
getMenuItems().then(response => {
    const item = response.data;
    return(
        <div>
            { console.log(item) }
            { item.map(menu => {
                return (
                   // ...
                );
            })};
        </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of data? You could paste in pastebin and share the link.

Comment: Paul, it seems to be an invalid JSON, could you make `JSON.stringify(data)` and paste the output to the pastebin service. I believe I could help you =)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/km399QFQ better

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve. It's not clear what you want. In both levels of depth, `children` is an array, not an object. What do you mean you want to retrieve both of them? Are there more than two levels deep? And what's the quote example you have in the question?

Comment: i edit, its better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, I've made a simple showcase for you: https://m1go3.csb.app/.
There is a recursive function component to render nested `children` items.

Here is the link to the source: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hofstadter-m1go3