# How return a const or function in primary function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a page with react components.

For that, I want to separate my code in several parts.

I want to create a page in my Layout function that uses various components like my MenuComponent.

However, I do not understand how to recover my MenuComponent in my Layout.

Thanks for your help.

```
  function Menu () {
  const [menuItems, setItems] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMenuItems().then(setItems);
  }, []);

  if (!menuItems) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <div>

        {menuItems.data.root.children.map(menu => {
          return (
              <TreeItem key={menu.id} nodeId="1" label={menu.text} labelIcon={Label}>

                {menu.children.map(child => {
                    return (
                    <TreeItem key={child.id} nodeId="1" label={child.text} labelIcon={Label}>
                      {console.log(child.text)}
                    </TreeItem>

                    );
                  })}
              </TreeItem>
          );
        })}
      </div>
  );
}

export default function Layout() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  if (!isLogged()) {
    return (
      <div className="fondLogin" fullscreen>
        <SnackbarProvider
          maxSnack={1}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "center"
          }}
        >
          <Login onSuccess />
        </SnackbarProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="containerGeneral">
      <InactivityManager />
      <Menu />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: the menu const isn't have the component rendered;
checkout this mate https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satif is completely right, if you are using a hooks approach, then you should make an async calls into `useEffect` hook.

Another thing, your component should always return something. If you want to prevent render just return `null`. In your case you are returning `undefined`.

```
function Menu () {
  const [menuItems, setItems] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMenuItems().then(setItems);
  }, []);

  if (!menuItems) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {menuItems.children.map(menu => {
            return (
                <TreeItem key={menu.id} nodeId="1" label={menu.text} labelIcon={Label}>

                </TreeItem>
            );
        })};
    </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: Maybe defining the default state as an empty array would be better?

Comment: It's just a showcase. It depends on `menuItems` type. Here I see that it is an object with some keys in it. You can define default state as an empty object and check `Object.keys(defaultState).length === 0`. It's not a big deal.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. I thought it was an array when I first looked at the code.

Comment: i can't add my submenu, i add a return with : menu.children.map(child => { return ( <TreeItem></>

Comment: I don't get it. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I tried to add a "RETURN" with the childrens of the menu ( i edit my code )

Comment: Oh, I see now. The best way to render a nested tree component is a recursive component. I've already sent you an example of it in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57954232/3914350. Try to use this approach here.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Welcome to SO Paul =)

Answer (score 0):

The menu component is wrong. You need to fetch a data in useEffect or componentDidMount methods.